# Cannot use AWS KMS key with AWS Encryption CLI but works with AWS Encryption SDK for Java

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, encryption

We have implemented encryption/decryption on individual database fields using the AWS Encryption SDK for Java. We use a AWS KSM key for the task and this works as it should.

Now we also need to access the decrypted data from a Python utility script. Using the example code we wrote:

```
def decrypt_string(key_arn, ciphertext, botocore_session=None):
    # Set up an encryption client with an explicit commitment policy. If you do not explicitly choose a
    # commitment policy, REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT is used by default.
    client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT)

    # Create an AWS KMS master key provider
    kms_kwargs = dict(key_ids=[key_arn])
    if botocore_session is not None:
        kms_kwargs["botocore_session"] = botocore_session
    master_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(**kms_kwargs)

    # Decrypt the ciphertext
    plaintext, decrypted_header = client.decrypt(source=ciphertext, key_provider=master_key_provider)

    print(plaintext)
```

The commitment policy is the same for the Java and Python implementation. When we invoke the function with the same ARN for the key and the raw cipher text we get the following error:

```
aws_encryption_sdk.exceptions.NotSupportedError: Unsupported signing algorithm info
```

Thinking we might have done something wrong we also installed the AWS Encryption CLI and tried to decode the same cipher text:

```
echo '<base64-encoded cipher text>' | \
aws-encryption-cli \
  --decrypt
  --decode
  --wrapping-keys key=<KMS KEY ARN>
  --commitment-policy require-encrypt-require-decrypt
  -S
  --input -
  --output -
```

But this resulted in the same error.

Next we just tried to encode some sample text using the AWS Encryption CLI but again we got the same error.

The KMS key is described as:

```
{
    "KeyMetadata": {
        "AWSAccountId": "<account-id>",
        "KeyId": "<key-id>",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:<account-id>:key/<key-id>",
        "CreationDate": "2023-06-07T10:35:18.466000+02:00",
        "Enabled": true,
        "Description": "",
        "KeyUsage": "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT",
        "KeyState": "Enabled",
        "Origin": "AWS_KMS",
        "KeyManager": "CUSTOMER",
        "CustomerMasterKeySpec": "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT",
        "KeySpec": "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT",
        "EncryptionAlgorithms": [
            "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"
        ],
        "MultiRegion": false
    }
}
```

Is the key not created properly or am I missing something else?

Software installed with `pip`:

- aws-encryption-sdk: 3.1.1
- aws-encryption-sdk-cli: 4.1.0
- boto3: 1.26.148

Software installed for the Java implementation:

- org.bouncycastle.bcprov-ext-jdk18on: 1.73
- com.amazonaws.aws-encryption-sdk-java: 2.4.0

Comment: Only comment i have for Java is to use AWS SDK for Java V2 (software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.KmsClient) - which is recommended over V1. V2 Code is here -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/kms

Comment: That seems to be coming from line 185 of https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-python/blob/master/src/aws_encryption_sdk/internal/crypto/elliptic_curve.py Have you tried running that in a debugger to see what trips the condition?

Comment: Do you get the same error with .NET or Dart https://pub.dev/packages/aws_encryption_sdk

Comment: @smac2020 With the Java code we use v2 of the SDK using `software.amazon.awssdk.services.kmssdkv2.KmsClient` otherwise it will fail on loading the KMS code.

Comment: @RichardHeap I've looked at the code but it doesn't provide with a possible solution to my problem. I've created the KMS key as described in the documentation and it still fails.

Comment: @RichardHeap Haven't tried any other languages besides the CLI and Python. But when I'm back in the office I will take a look.

Comment: @smac2020 To clarify, we access the KSM key through the AWS Encryption SDK and not directly.

Comment: It looks like related to this issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-cli/issues/307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Found a similar [ticket on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-cli/issues/307).
Info from the ticket helped to recover from the issue - although [requirements file](https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-python/blob/v3.1.1/requirements.txt) for `aws-encryption-sdk: 3.1.1` lists `cryptography>=2.5.0` it did cause an issue.
Upgrading cryptography package to `41.0.7` has solved the issue for me.

Comment: This indeed solved my issue. Thanks.